# Identity expression, factor, and term?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am learning context-free grammar, and I don't understand how to identity expression, factor and term in a programming language like C or C++.

Suppose we have an assignment statement,  **id := E**, where E is any arithmetic expression.

What is a term? What is an expression? and What is a factor in an actual piece of code?

We can have

```
int i = 3, j = 14
int i = 3 + j * 14;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlexK that's correct. But I want to see what expression, factor and term are in an actual piece of code. Thank you though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The "factor", "term" and "expression" concepts come from math and don't really have to do with programming languages.

Factors are things you multiply:

```
1*2*(3+4)
```

Terms are things you add:

```
1 + 2 + (3*4)
```

And expressions are for the whole result

```
1 + 3 * 7
```

In context-free language parsing you use these distinctions to organize the precedences between operators. So an expression is made of a sum of terms and a term is made of a product of factors and a factor is either a number or a parenthesized subexpression.

Comment: Can you please define "statement" in this way(adding an example will be appreciated)

Comment: kindly use one example `1+3*7` and show the expression, terms, and factors distinctively.

Answer (score 1):

Your homework probably also has a grammar specification for a (subset of a) programming language like C or C++ , something along the lines of:

Program->Expression|Definition|Declaration
Expression->Expression + Term
Expression->Expression - Term
Expression->Expression*Factor
...
...
...
etc etc.

Then, 3 + j*14 is an expression, 3 is a term (anything connected by a + is either an Expression or a Term according to the grammar above)  j and 14 are factors
Please note that a grammar above is a very crude imitation of what a grammar of a real programming language might look like.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so suppose we have a grammar like this:

Program->(Definitions | lambda)
Definitions->Definitions Definitions

Definitions-> "int" Definition ";" |"int" Definition,Definition ";"
Definition -> Name "=" Expression

Expression-> Term "+" Expression
Expression->Expression "-" Term
Expression->Expression "*" Factor
Term->"3"|"14"
Factor->"3"|"14"
Expression->"3"|"14"

Note that my terminal symbols are in quotes and I omit the part where Name is defined as a combination of letters and numbers and underscores starting with a letter or an underscore :)

So, in your example:

Line 1 int i = 3, j = 14;
Line 2 int i = 3 + j * 14;

i and j are Names. 3, 14 (line 1) and 3 + j*14 (line 2) are  are Expressions. Then,on line   2, 3 is a Term, j*14 is an Expression, j is a Factor and 14 is a Factor :)