# How can I understand this binary expression grammar?

Tags: grammar, bnf

I don't understand this binary expression grammar

```
expr -> expr '+' term
      | expr '-' term
      | term

term -> term '*' factor
      | term '/' factor
      | factor

factor -> '(' expr ')'
        | NUM
```

Comment: what is it you don't understand? `->` means that the left operand can take the values of the right, `|` means that the value before and the value after are valid, and that's about it.

Comment: for example: `3` is a NUM, so it is a valid factor, a valid term, and a valid expr. `3*4` is a factor * factor, so it is a valid term, and a valid expr, and so on.

Comment: The grammer describes an [infix expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation).

Comment: @ikegami: no, they're not. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8056203/1566221 But people (including me) swap them around so often that it's not really clear what's normal. The author of the linked answer definitely gets it right: a factor is a one or the other of the numbers you multiply to get a new  number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identity expression, factor, and term?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055605/identity-expression-factor-and-term)

Answer (score 1):

In plain english:

An `expr` can be one of the following:

- another `expr` followed by the character `+` followed by a `term`
- another `expr` followed by the character `-` followed by a `term`
- a `term`

A `term` can be one of the following:

- another `term` followed by the character `*` followed by a `factor`
- another `term` followed by the character `/` followed by a `factor`
- a `factor`

A `factor` can be one of the following:

- a character `(` followed by and `expr` followed by a character `)`
- a number